# Using 24 hours format on an English-speaking website

Tags: website-design, time

I'm currently developing a dashboard for monitoring some objects that my corporation designs and manipulates. Those objects come with a date and time, that I translate from a cron table. In [standard CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression), hours are expressed within the range 0-23 so it'd be great if I could express the time in a 24 hours format, that'd relieve me from the need of translating into AM/PM format.

**I really would like to make my website user-friendly for everyone**: I don't mind having to write more code, but I know that in the country I'm working in, people aren't very familiar with the AM/PM format and my coworkers are **likely to get confused between times in the morning and past noon**. As those latter represent the main pool of users for my website, I'd like to think a format that suit everyone, them and the English-speaking users.

Are English-speaking people familiar with the 24 hours format for expressing times?

Comment: I'd be hard-pressed to say which is more common in the UK: probably because both are used and I translate as necessary without thinking about it. But the 24-hour is certainly common, especially in timetables (busses, trains, planes).

Comment: Any reason to not give the user the option to toggle between AM/PM & 24hr time formats?

Comment: Always default to 24-hour format in international contexts. Nobody knows whether 12 pm or 12 am is 12:00 (noon) or 00:00 (midnight, start of day) and 24:00 (end of day) is not available at all if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Language and Regional preferences are two different things: there are english-speaking countries that use [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) and there are non-english countries that use [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), and some use both. Moreover, how they use the 12-hour clock may differ, or they can use a completely different time format.

I think, proper solution would be change the display based on user's local preferences: in some cases you could even fetch the preferences from the device or browser (for example, by using [toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)), that way the user would see the time the way they expect it to be.

Comment: Agree: allowing the user to select the format seems the best way, either explicitly within your app, or based on their locale settings.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S., the majority go by AM/PM and a great majority doesn’t know what to do with 0-24, unless they’ve been in the military or similar type of public service. I would definitely consider a solution that serves both depending on your audience.

Answer (score 1):

Show both, 24 hour format first and prominent, as it's the international format (ISO 8601), followed by less prominent AM/PM format.